# running a javaservice using the administrator user

Tags: java, user-permissions, java-service-wrapper

I have a Java application which I want to run it using the [JavaService](http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/devdocs/devcmds.html) wrapper.

The service works well when the -user parameter is not used (using the defaul user as local system).

For permissions reasons, I need use the administrator user as a owner of service, but the following message apears when I start it.

[image]

Translate: It can not start the service due to error in the login.

The service.exe install command is the following:

JavaService.exe -install "ServiceName" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll" -start "ServiceClass" -user ".\Administrador" -password "1234"

UPDATE:
If I change the user of the service using the services.msc console, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.

The Error message 1069 was caused then this user doesn't have permisions to logon as a service.

To add this permision [follow the steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327545):

- Open the ocal security settings (start -> run -> secpol.msc) if is not domain or setting the Default Domain Controller GPO is a Domain server.
- Expand Local Policies, and then click User Rights Assignment
- In the right pane, right-click Log on as a service, and then click Add User or Group